# Laravel Exceptions handling when debug=false

Tags: laravel, exception

I use the default Laravel Exception handler, but I have a question regarding good practices.

When I have a condition in which the controller must throw an exception, I do the following:

```
if($blah) {
    abort(500, "The user should not be here");
}
```

and then on the frontend, I have a view that handles the error as this:

```
@section('message', __($exception->getMessage() ?: 'Whoops, something went wrong on our servers.'))
```

So that works great as long as I have the following on the `.env` file:

```
APP_DEBUG=true
```

Whenever I change this value to false, (as it should in production), all I get on the error page is:   `Server Error` instead of my custom message.

How can I keep my custom error message, and have `APP_DEBUG=false` in production?

Comment: Any reason why you are throwing error 500. Look into HTTP error codes (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status) and use them appropriately. Based on the above example you have provided, if the user is not supposed to view that page, then throw a 404. What Laravel is doing for error 500 is correct. Laravel allows you to customize error pages (https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/errors#custom-http-error-pages) as required.

Comment: @Abishek: that was just an example. I throw 404 when not found or the appropiate code based on the situation.  It still doesn't emit the "message" on the error.  The same happens if I try to get it using json

Answer (score 0):

If you want to customize you HTTP errors for specific views or conditions, then you will have to look into [Rendering exceptions](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/errors#rendering-exceptions) section that will show you how to show a custom view for a specific exception. With this you can throw an exception like

```
throw new UserNotFoundException();
```

and listen to that exception and render a specific view as required.